# Corporate VPN on macOS disconnects when I answer a call on my iPhone while connected to local Wi-Fi. Why could this be?

Tags: macos, iphone, wifi, vpn, continuity

I work from home so I connect to my corporate VPN from my MacBook Pro (M1 Max/16").
My MBP is hardwired to my network.

Any time I get a call on my iPhone while I'm connected to Wi-Fi, the VPN connection drops as soon as I answer the call.

While my iPhone is ringing, I see a notification on my MBP for the call. I am not interacting with this Continuity notification. I am answering the call on my iPhone.

The VPN connection stays up while the phone is ringing, it's not until I answer it that it drops.

This doesnt happen if I have Wi-Fi disabled on my iPhone.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

I'm running macOS 14.2 and iOS 17.2 but this has been happening for months on prior OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a network engineer, so I can't explain why it disconnects your VPN, but I suspect it has something to do with needing similar external IP addresses in order for the continuity call feature to work on your Mac? Having a VPN would mask your external IP address and thus may break continuity features between your Mac and iPhone. Remember, the two devices need to be physically nearby to each other and on the same wifi network to be able to use continuity/handoff, so, if one device is identifying as being connected to a server in London (i.e. your Mac over it's VPN) and your other device (i.e. your iPhone) is identifying as being connected to a server in Paris, it would suggest that these devices are not in fact right next to each other and thus continuity breaks?

Once again, I reiterate, I am not a network engineer, so I don't know the specifics of how it all works. I'm just a mere macOS enthusiast. :)

However, one solution you could do to prevent your VPN from disconnecting is to disable making iPhone calls on nearby Apple devices in iOS Settings. Go to `Settings`>`Phone`>`Calls on Other Devices`. In this settings menu you will see two (or more) toggles you can disable/enable. The first option   allows you to entirely disable making calls on all Apple devices you own, whilst the second option will allow you to selectively enable which Apple devices you wish to allow calls from. So if you have a non-work Mac that you do wish to allow calls from, you could leave it enabled and just disable your work's Mac from being able to make/receive calls from it.

I've attached a screenshot of the settings menu showing these options.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll definitely try this tomorrow and see if it gets addressed. I'm also curious as to what the logs show for the VPN so I need to gather those as well.